# PHP JQuery Checkbox Array - Selecting only 1 value

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Following is an ajax post page which renders the checkboxes on run-time. I am facing issue while writting the script for select all  button, when I click on the button only 1 value is getting selected not the entire array:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
include("../includes/functions.php");


if(isset($_REQUEST['t']))
{
    $td = $_REQUEST['t'];

    $t = split(",",$td);
    $all = "";
    $box_in_row = 0 ;
    $this_box="<table border=0><tr>";
    foreach($t as $table)
    {
        $this_box = "<td><h3>$table</h3>";
        $result = mysql_query("SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM $table FROM prfxcom1_prfx");
        $options = "";
        while($r = mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            if(!empty($r->Comment))
            {
                $options .= "<br><input type=checkbox name=\"".$table."[]\" value='$r->Field' id=\"$table\">" . $r->Field;

            }
        }

        if($table == "transfer_req")
        {
            $options .= "<br><input type=checkbox name=\"".$table."[]\" value='Net Profit' id=\"$table\">NetProfit";

        }

        $this_box .=  $options;

        // Button
        $click = "$('#$table').attr('checked', 'checked')";

        $button = "<br /><input style='margin-top:10px;' type='button' name='$table_button' id='$table_button' value=' Select All ' onclick=\"$click\"/>";
        $all .= "<div class='tblBox'>".$this_box.$button."</div></td>";

    }
    //$all = "<table class=\"listing form\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">".$all."</table>";
    echo $all;
}

?>
```

Issue is faced in the line:

```
$click = "$('#$table').attr('checked', 'checked')";
```

Please suggest, I am stuck on this.

Thanks,
Hardik

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the many issues with the code and simply answering the question:

You need to refer to the checkboxes using a class name not a ID (you have given them all the same ID)

For these lines:  `$options .= "<br><input type=checkbox name=\"".$table."[]\" value='$r->Field' id=\"$table\">" . $r->Field;`

Change to:  `$options .= "<br><input type=checkbox name='" . $table . "[]' value='" . $r->Field ."' class='" . $table . "'>" . $r->Field;`

For this line: `$click = "$('#$table').attr('checked', 'checked')";` use single quotes or escape the $

Change to: `$click = '$("."'.$table.'").attr("checked", "checked")';`

Comment: Hi Andre, It's not working for $click = "('#$table//[//]').attr('checked', 'checked')";

Answer (score 0):

WHAT???

```
$click = "$('#$table').attr('checked', 'checked')";
```

How can you write Javascript in the middle of a PHP file? It needs to be in script tags but even then PHP runs at the server and will not render your Javascript for you.

Add `script` tags, change your ID's to separate ones and give them the same class like `tableClassName`, and then write the following.

```
$(function(){
    $('.tableClassName').attr('checked', 'checked')";
});
```

Comment: Hi, I am just trying make modification in the working code, where it was working with dropdown..